# regex search in vi for a line that contains a string but does *not* end with, say, Q

Tags: regex, match

Using vi, I want to match a string, but only if the line doesn't end with some letter, say Q.

E.g., if the file is:

```
myQ
my
```

I want to match the first line but not the second.

From reading related posts it *would seem* that look aheads should work:

```
/[?=my][?!Q]
```

should find just the second line
but it finds the first.

Comment: `/^.\+[^Q]$/` should do the trick

Comment: @MichaelWild: This should be an answer :)

Comment: @Mr.TAMER well, the question is too simple ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with the following

```
/^.\+[^Q]$^/
```

Comment: There's a backslash missing in front of the + operator, otherwise vim interprets it as a literal + (unless you modify the magic-ness). I couldn't fix it though, because stupid SO wants edit to be a minimum of six characters long!

Comment: Don't blame SO, blame me for not having reread my answer ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Can't seem to get the edit box to take a linefeed, sorry for the unreadability of this post.    Thanks very much guys for all your responses.    I had tried to simplify my question to its essence but I clearly tried too hard.  Suppose my text is
CR
my CR
myQ CR
your CR
yourQ      

Then based on what MrTAMER said, I would expect 

/^my.\+[Q^]$/ 

to find just the first line, but it doesn't find anything.   

I'm also puzzled by Thomas's suggestion, first since the backslash before the + is now there, and second because I don't understand the difference between Michael's suggestion and Thomas's

Answer (score 0):

Vim has a regex syntax different from Perl's, but we shouldn't need zero-width matches for your purpose.

```
/my\(.*[^Q]\|\)$
```